# MassTransit having business logic / behavior in sagas

Tags: masstransit

The event handlers for sagas seem to have business logic / behavior embedded in them.
I'm referring to the Starbucks example.

Is this done intentionally due the "sample app" nature of the example?
Doesn't the domain logic / behavior seem very tightly bound to mass transit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dru from MT got back to me in the google group (paraphrase): The sample was written to be very simple, separate the business logic and call it in the saga.